# Скачет навигационная панель при наведении на ссылку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

По какой причине скачет панель при наведении на ссылку? `margin-right` между ссылками должен быть `30px`.

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: url(../img/header-background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 23px;
}

.phone {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.phone__icon {
  padding-right: 7px;
  color: #bec8c8;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__item a {
  color: #b3bfbf;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__item a:hover {
  background-color: #6a7f80;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Wapik</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300|Montserrat|Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <div class="logo">
            WAPIK
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 mt-auto mb-auto">
          <div class="phone">
            <i class="fas fa-phone-alt phone__icon"></i>+62 202 555 0117
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
          <nav>
            <ul class="menu d-flex">
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">pricing</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Подправил, можете сверить со своим кодом. При необходимости подправите еще как вам нужно.

```css
.header{
 padding-top: 30px;
 background: url(../img/header-background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

.logo{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 29px;
 text-align: center;
    
    padding-right: 23px;
}

.phone{
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.phone__icon{
 padding-right: 7px;
 color: #bec8c8;
}

.menu{
 list-style: none; 
 justify-content:flex-end;
 padding-top: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu__item{
  display: inline-block;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 margin-right: 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__item a{
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
 color: #b3bfbf;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__item a:hover{
 background-color: #6a7f80;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <title>Wapik</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300|Montserrat|Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <header class="header">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2">
          <div class="logo">
            WAPIK
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2 mt-auto mb-auto">
            <div class="phone">
              <i class="fas fa-phone-alt phone__icon"></i>+62 202 555 0117
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">pricing</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в одну строку все поместилось

Comment: @Famous сейчас все в одной строке, не так?

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. А в чем заключалась проблема ? Чтобы на будущее знать. Из-за того,что margin-right 30px ?

Comment: не только, у вас в `.menu__item a:hover` был `padding: 10px;` а его нужно было указать в `.menu__item a` и для `.menu__item a` указать свойство `display: block;`

Comment: Я вот ставлю margin-right 30px - и все опять съезжает. В чем причина ?

Comment: в том, что таким образом вы сдвигаете каждый пункт меню на 30px. если хотите сдвинуть все меню, тогда `margin-right: 30px;` укажите для `.menu`

Comment: нет, я как раз-таки хочу сделать между пунктами margin-right 30px

Comment: что-то со стороны bootstrap'a ломает, позже посмотрю, если меня не опередят

Comment: исправил как вам нужно. в `.menu__item` добавил `display: inline-block;` и из `<ul class="menu d-flex">` удалил класс `d-flex` @Famous